# Why can a static library be linked despite undefined references (missing `extern "C"`)?

Tags: c++, c, linker, static-libraries

I don't have a problem that needs solving but was very puzzled by the following:

I'm using CMake (which uses gcc internally). Not sure if this is important.

Suppose I have a project consisting of a C++ static library LibCpp and a demo C++ executable DemoCpp, which links to and uses LibCpp. The library LibCpp is compiled from both C and C++ sources. The correct way to do this is for the C++ code files of LibCpp to inlucde all C headers as `extern "C" {#include "c_header.h"}`. If this is done, the static library links fine and the executable DemoCpp sucessfully links to LibCpp. Everything works.

Suppose, that I forgot to put in the `extern "C"`'s and just include the C headers as C++ headers. As expected, the full project fails to link. However, and this is what puzzles me, the **linking fails when DemoCpp tries to link to LibCpp!** I would have expected it to fail already at linking the static library. However, the static library (e.g. `LibCpp.a` file) are built just fine, it just cannot be used.

This is very puzzling to me, because to link the static library (I would think) the linker has to resolve the references into the code compiled as C. This is also annoying in my opinion, since I cannot rely on a library being "linkable to" only since the library itself managed to be linked. Am I missing something?

**You do not need to look at below code examples**, unless you don't understand my question or don't believe what I said.

```cmake
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)

project(LibraryLinkerEvil)

# Toggle this line to see that linking fails for DemoCpp BUT NOT FOR LibCpp!!!
add_compile_definitions(USE_EXTERN_C)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
add_library(LibCpp cpp_lib.cpp util.c)

add_executable(DemoCpp main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(DemoCpp PRIVATE LibCpp)
```

```
// cpp_lib.cpp
#ifdef USE_EXTERN_C
extern "C" {
#endif

#include "util.h"

#ifdef USE_EXTERN_C
}
#endif

int call_c_function(int a, int b) {
    return add(a,b);
}
```

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>

int call_c_function(int a, int b); // could be in a separate C++ header.

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World! " << call_c_function(2,2) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

```c
// util.h (C header)
#ifndef LIBRARYLINKEREVIL_UTIL_H
#define LIBRARYLINKEREVIL_UTIL_H

int add(int a, int b);

#endif //LIBRARYLINKEREVIL_UTIL_H
```

```
// util.c (C source file)
int add(int a, int b) {
    return a+b;
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised it gets to the linking step. Here's why: `malloc` requires an output cast in C++, but not in C.

Comment: @EvanHendler I don't see malloc anywhere in the question

Comment: That's not the point of the comment. I'm sure `malloc` exists somewhere in a dependency. And if not `malloc`, then some other function with slightly differing syntax between C and C++. `Extern "C"` should always be used when including C code.

Comment: @EvanHendler I don't think it's very useful to make a comment based on an assumption not evidenced in the post.

Comment: Ok, so I should rephrase it to the most generic case.

Comment: @EvanHendler I don't think it's that surprising. Leaving `extern "C"` off a function only changes how you can use it if you're passing it to something that expects an `extern "C"` function (e.g. `qsort` for example). If you aren't doing that then there's no problem. A custom `void* mymalloc(size_t)` function for example would be called the same way in C++ whether or not it's `extern "C"`.

Comment: Yeah, given that this is `util.h` it probably doesn't depend on on `glibc`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would have expected it to fail already at linking the static library.

The static "library" is not linked. Its constituent object files are archived - bundled together in an **object archive** for convenience's sake. That's what the static "library" is. You can think of it as a bunch of object files packed in a "zip" file that the linker can then decode.

So, the only linking the object archive undergoes is when the target binary itself is linked (be it into a .dll/.so or executable).

The use of the object archive is equivalent to the use of the constituent object files: instead of passing the archive to the linker, you can pass all the object files it contained, with same results.

On Unix, the typical name for the tool that manages object archives is `ar` (`ar`chiver) - a very descriptive name indeed. In Unix tradition, the static "libraries" are called *object archives*. The term static "library" is a confusing misnomer and should be banned.

Usually `ar` is a much smaller program than the linker - often an order of magnitude smaller. The most rudimentary archiving is just a concatenation with a header added.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! How about a shared library? I tried the same thing with a dynamic library (by putting `SHARED` into the `add_library` command) and still got a `libLibCpp.so` file.

Comment: @AdomasBaliuka On most systems, the shared library is basically an executable without the executable's entry point and without a flag set in the header. E.g. `.dll` and `.exe` are the same PE format with same functionality, just a few bits (literally) of difference - and you can import symbols from an `.exe`! Same on Linux: a shared library is like an "unfinished" executable - the binary format is ELF, and if you want, you can export symbols from the "executable" and have them imported by a shared library you runtime load. So when you think "shared library" think "executable" with a flag set 0

Comment: Thanks! What you say would seem to imply that I can't link my "missing extern C" library as a shared library. However, I can do that as well. If you can update your answer with the comment about shared libraries and the reason the shared library links as well, I can accept your answer.

Comment: You should ask a different question about linking shared libraries with missing symbols, and please be direct: the problem has nothing to do with "extern C", but with presence/absence of symbols, so instead you can just manually mismatch the function names etc. and get same result without introducing another layer of complication.

Comment: I take this to mean that a shared library can also be linked without resolving all symbols? When linking an executable, all symbols must be resolved, right?

Answer (score 1):

Because C++ supports function overloading, function names are "mangled" during the compilation process so that they have unique names in the object file.  Using `extern "C"` prevents that mangling from happening.

If you leave out `extern "C"` when compiling, then `call_c_function` is expecting to call a C++ function with the name `add`, in particular the mangled name would be `_Z3addii`.  Since `add` exists in a .c file it has the unmangled name instead of the mangled name, so now `_Z3addii` is considered an external function just like `printf`, and like all other external functions they are expected to be resolved at link time of the executable, not compile time, and not when the static library is created.

When you create a static library, you're not actually linking.  You're just grouping several object files together into a larger archive.  That way, when linking actually happens, you only need to link a single file instead of multiple.

Comment: My question is NOT why I need `extern "C"`. My question is WHY the static library links despite not using `extern "C"`

Comment: Is it being compiled with flag `-c` initially?

Comment: @AdomasBaliuka Static libraries don't need to resolve external functions when they are linked.  The final resolution of externals only happens when an executable is linked.

Comment: @dbush why didn't you write that in your answer?

Comment: @AdomasBaliuka I've updated with details on static library creation.

Answer (score 1):

Not all references need to be resolved when creating a library. What if your library code has dependencies on another library? Those references aren't resolved when the library is created. They're resolved when you link the library to your executable, in which case you need to also link it with other libraries to provide those dependencies.

Library `liba.a`:

```
void from_b();
void from_a()
{
    from_b();
}
```

Libary `libb.a`:

```
void from_b()
{
    ...
}
```

main.cpp:

```
void from_a();
int main()
{
    from_a();
}
```

Compiling/linking:

```
g++ main.cpp -la -lb
```

Without `-lb` you'd get an undefined reference error here.

Comment: *Not all references need to be resolved when creating a library.* This is technically true but very misleading. **No references are resolved when creating an object archive** (object archive is the proper term for a static "library" - it is self-descriptive and doesn't mislead). Creating an object archive is just bundling together object files. Nothing is being resolved, no linking is performed, and on Unix the name of the tool to do this is `ar`: for *archiver*.